# Is 'measurement' deterministic in the pilot wave theory?

Tags: determinism, bohmian-mechanics, quantum-measurements

From what I read, measurements in pilot wave theory affect the particles as well as the guiding waves. Is it a random process or is everything deterministic according to the theory?

Answer (score 0):

The wave function come guiding wave evolves in a purely deterministic manner, including how it changes upon measurement. In PWT the guided particle is said to follow deterministic trajectories, which can be calculated if we have initial conditions: particle position & momentum, at some instant in time. The problem is when we take measurements to attempt to ascertain these at some instant, we are frustrated by the Heisenberg uncertainty principle, and so cannot calculate the future trajectory of a particle. This was said to be due to our ignorance, of factors determining the precise behaviour of the particle. However, the Heisenberg uncertainty is inherent in any wave function, so there would have to be information concerning the particle, that exists outside the guiding wave; hidden information/variables. Given Bell’s theorem, there can be no local hidden variables; so any such information cannot be carried by the particle. Making it unlikely there are any determining factors. In fact even Bohm, while initially calling his theory the Causal interpretation, changed it to the Ontological interpretation. So while PWT was initially entirely deterministic, there is now at least some doubt as to whether the particles behaviour is actually so, at least when measured.